# Issue with MySQL, Android and PHP

Tags: php, android, mysql

I can find tons of examples where you can query a MySQL database from Android with name value pairs like in [this example](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database), and I can get that to work just fine.

Now, however, I want to make it even simpler and that's when I run into problems. I want to simply return an entire table with the query below.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","username","pw");
mysql_select_db("db");

$q=mysql_query("SELECT field FROM table");

while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
        $output[]=$e;

print(json_encode($output));

mysql_close();

?>
```

So no $_REQUEST lines are being used which is the main difference. The PHP code works fine by itself when I run it in the web browser.

The problem arises in the Android code below. It fails when running the final httpclient.execute line.

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://site.com/db.php");
//httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

The error returned is android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException.

I don't know if the setEntity part here is needed since I have no actual nameValuePairs that needs to be received by the PHP script? I have tried both commenting it out as above and setting some dummy value pairs, it won't connect either way. I suspect the setEntity part is where the problem is. How would I set the entity in this case? Or is it a different problem? Thanks.

UPDATE:
I tried changing HttpPost to HttpGet as below, but still get the same problem.

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://site.com/db.php");
//httpget.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
```

Comment: what kind of problems are you running into?

Comment: The "HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);" line in the java code fails. I'll try to edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Why HttpPost when you should be using HttpGet?

Comment: Hmm, because that's what all the examples I've seen have used :). Nevertheless I tried switching to HttpGet (see updated question) but still get the same thing.

Comment: Alrighty - so what's the stack trace of the exception you're getting? Or is it a HTTP error returned in the HttpResponse?

Comment: I'm a bit of a newb when it comes to debugging in Eclipse, but the log returns "android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException" as Exception. Is there a better way I can debug this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this question: [How to fix android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

That exception is thrown when you perform networking operations on the main thread, which is bad practice because it hurts responsiveness of your app. You should use a background thread to do the work.

Comment: *facepalm* That was the problem. It's annoying because I actually already knew about this and had solved it once before. Thanks for reminding me. An alternative (but sloppy?) solution to starting a new thread by the way is to change the policy with the following code. `StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);`